# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux-form'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I faced this issue while im installing redux can someone help me I tried to install redux form by using this cmd line :

npm install react-redux-form@latest --save

**package.json:**

```
  "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.10.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
```

Can you please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it with : `npm install react-redux-form@1.16.8 --save --force`